# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in woocommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

**For code:**

```
foreach ($statuses as $status_slug => $status) {
    printf('<input type="checkbox" id="status_filter[]" name="status_filter[]" value="%s" /> %s<br />', $status_slug, $status);
 }
```

**Get Error:**

> **Catchable Fatal Error:** Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string in woocommerce plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try to search backwards and see the place where the object is created/instantiated and then if you forgot to do so, then do it, or otherwise get rid of the line which uses it, if it is not meant to be there. or check for spelling errors making sure you are using the right variable that hold that object, thease are possible w